# Python: How to delete all non-alphanumeric keys in a Dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I made a dictionary that counts the number of occurrences of a symbol in a text file. However, I want to *exclude* all non-alphanumeric keys (I want to keep all the letter keys, upper- and lowercase).

**How do I write a function to do this?**

Ultimately I want to have the new dictionary sorted in alphabetical order.

i.e. from `{' ': 4, 'e': 2, 'a': 1}` to `{'a': 1,'e': 2}`

Comment: It is not difficult but can you post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension.

```
a = {' ': 4, 'e': 2, 'a': 1}
a = { key:val for key,val in a.iteritems() if key.isalnum() }
print a
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'e': 2}
```

> I want to have the new dictionary sorted in alphabetical order.

For this part, dictionary have no order, so you can't sort them. What you can do is to make tuples by `dict.iteritems()` and then sort them  based on keys or values.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `OrderedDict` if you want to maintain a specific order in a dictionary:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = {' ': 4, 'e': 2, 'a': 1} 
od = OrderedDict(sorted((k,v) for k,v in d.items() if k.isalpha()))

print(od)
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('e', 2)])
```